Unable to Run Intell HXAM Installer

I'm getting this Issue. where it says that "Running Intel® HAXM installer
'C:\Users\Danish' is not recognized as an internal or external command"
My question is how to resolve this. Also i have tried almost all the things but not working. Is it because of the space after Danish?
I have seen many queries on this regard also installed hxam directly but that also resulted nothing. The problem remains the same
